# Evaluating a Sine Limit Using the Squeeze Theorem

Tags: limits

It is quite obvious that the answer is 1 by just directly substituting the value 0 for x but I can't figure out which mathematical fact or whatever we originate from when it comes to reaching such an inequality. Hope I'm clear.
It might be that the book only expects me to plug in the value and get 1 as the result but in that case I want to go further.

it goes:

1-((x^2)/6 =< (sin(x))/x =< 1 for x near 0

evaluate the limit at x = 0 for (sin(x))/x

I tried using -1 =< sin(x) =< 1 as a starting point but got lost and miscalculated the limit of sin(x)/x as infinity.

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Note that "substituting for $x$" is not automatically a valid method for evaluating limits—it works only when the function is continuous, and in particular defined. In this case, you are given three functions $f,g,h$ such that $f(x)\le g(x)\le h(x)$ near $x=0$. It sounds like you can also evaluate $\lim_{x\to0} f(x)$ and $\lim_{x\to0} h(x)$. Once you have these facts verified, what does the Squeeze Theorem tell you about $\lim_{x\to0} g(x)$?